# Use a Tiledmap service as basemap instead of an Arcgis.com map in AMD style coding

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How will I define a arcgisTiled map service as the base map (instead of “topo”) as against using arcgis.com map services while defining a new map in AMD style?

```
map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-122.445, 37.752],
          zoom: 14
        });
```

I would like to replace "topo" with a map tiledservice from my server:

```
http://ourserver/arcgis/rest/services/tiledmapservice/MapServer
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply not set the basemap in the Map constructor and add an ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer pointing to your endpoint.

API Reference:
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/flex/api-reference/com/esri/ags/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.html

Example:

```
<script>
  var map;

  require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Map, Tiled) {
      map = new Map("map");

      var tiled = new Tiled("http://ourserver/arcgis/rest/services/tiledmapservice/MapServer");
      map.addLayer(tiled);
    }
  );
</script>
```

A full sample is available at:
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/layers_ags_tiled.html

Comment: Thanks, but how can I put map options in this case? If I put these options while creating new map:
{
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-122.445, 37.752],
          zoom: 14
        }---Div will be empty?? Any further thoughts?

Comment: You can still add the options object to the map constructor, just don't include the basemap property if you don't want it. 

Also, remember that the first layer added to the map object will set certain properties like spatial reference and tile level info.